# Modify @section rendering process

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

I'm working on a SPA which I would like to make available for users who have javascript disabled. In order to achieve this I use ajax helper methods for my submit and navigation buttons, which by default fall back to regular http requests when scripts are disabled.

I then render each of my partials as full Views in my controllers and  override the _ViewStart.cshtml with the following:

```
@{
    Layout = Request.IsAjaxRequest() || ViewContext.IsChildAction
        ? null
        : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

By doing this, ajax requests essentially return partials, while non-ajax requests will use a layout and return the full view.

The problem I have with this is that I have to then include some logic in each of my views to make sure @section doesn't get hit when the view is being rendered without a layout. Here's an example:

```
@{

    bool _partial = Request.IsAjaxRequest() || ViewContext.IsChildAction;

    Layout = _partial ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
@if (!_partial)
{

    @section Styles{ 
        <style>
           **some style**
        </style>
    }

    @section Scripts{ 
        <script type="text/javascript">
           **some script**
        </script>               
    }

    ** body **

}
else
{
    <style>
        **some style**
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        **some script**
    </script>

    ** body **      
}
```

Essentially, this means that I have to duplicate code for each view, which gets messy as I have to update both sets of code when I make changes. Is there any way I can write an extension for @section that will allow me to perform the _partial check and either render using RenderSection or HTML accordingly wherever @section is used (eg., @section Scripts{} or HTML script tags) so that I only need to write a single View?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">..` seems a bit pointless in the `else` statement is javascript is disabled

Comment: Oh its there in case a user navigates directly to the url rather than through an ajax call

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to do this in the end without having to modify anything.Note that in my case, I was using bundles in my layout so it was easy for me to maintain 2 copies of @section styles/scripts (single line each).

To achieve the desired effect, including multiple nesting scenarios, this was my method:

NestedLayout1.cshtml (inherits from main layout)

```
@{

    bool _partial = Request.IsAjaxRequest() || ViewContext.IsChildAction;

    Layout = _partial ? null : "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
@if (!_partial)
{    

    @section Styles{

        **styles**

    }

    @section Scripts{

        **scripts**

    }

}
else
{ 

    <style type="text/css">

       **styles** 

    </style>

}

** layout body ** // this may also contain the @Render fns below

@RenderBody() // ** this is the key line to pass the render body function **
@RenderSection("Content") // your js and css files
```

This nested layout could then be used by a partial as follows:

```
@{

    bool _partial = Request.IsAjaxRequest() || ViewContext.IsChildAction;

    Layout = _partial ? null : "~/Views/Shared/NestedLayout1.cshtml";

}

@if (!_partial)
{

@section Content{

    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.ready = function () {

            ** functions ** // You'll usually copy your ajax onLoad function here

        }

    </script>

}

}

** body **
```

There's still a little work, but not having to do the body twice solves most of my concerns anyway.